# How is the CUDA<<<...>>>() kernel launch syntax implemented

Tags: cuda, language-design

CUDA kernels are launched with this syntax (at least in the runtime API)

```
mykernel<<<blocks, threads, shared_mem, stream>>>(args);
```

Is this implemented as a macro or is it special syntax that nvcc removes before handing host code off to gcc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `nvcc` preprocessing system eventually converts it to a sequence of [CUDA runtime library calls](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION) before handing the code off to the host code compiler for compilation.   The exact sequence of calls may change depending on CUDA version.

You can inspect files using the `--keep` option to `nvcc` (and `--verbose` may help with understanding as well), and you can also see a trace of API calls issued for a kernel call using one of the profilers  e.g. `nvprof --print-api-trace ...`

---EDIT---

Just to make this answer more concise, nvcc directly modifies the host code to replace the <<<...>>> syntax before passing it off to the host compiler (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#offline-compilation)